# When to instantiate a struct explicitly?

Tags: go

i'm coming from Java, and there you always do something like:

```
Http http = new Http(...);

http.ListenAndServe();
```

So all information are stored in the local variable "http".

It's different in go. There most of the information is stored directly "in another package".

You do:

```
import "net/http"
...    
http.ListenAndServe(...)
```

So you dont have to explicitly (well you could) instantiate a server struct. Just call a function from the package and all the structs will be created from there. (So compared to Java, it acts like static functions with static member variables to store all information ?)

So this is how you do it (everytime) in go ?
Coming from Java, this is a little bit hard to understand.
Especially when to use this method, when to use a factory pattern (like: `NewHttpServer(...)` ) and when to explicitly create a struct from another package ( like: `var http http.Server = http.Server{...}` )

Everything might be possible, but what is the idiomatic golang code ?

Is there any good document/tutorial which explains it ?

Comment: Usually the rule is if you need any advance configuration you instantiate the object and it will have functions and properties for configuration, and use the package functions to use the functionality without an instance when the defaults are good enough for your use case.

Comment: Take the Tour of Go. Regarding your question: All variants have their use and none is idiomatic or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd really suggest reading the [Godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) for `net/http`. The package is very feature-rich and lets you do what you want.

The behaviour of `http.ListenAndServe` is to implicitly use a serve multiplexer known as `DefaultServeMux`, on which you can register handlers with `http.Handle`. So you can't deal with the server or multiplexer explicitly like this.

It sounds like what you want (a more Java-like solution) is to instantiate a server

```
s := &http.Server{
    Addr:           ":8080",
    Handler:        myHandler,        // takes a path and a http.HandlerFunc
    ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second, // optional config
    WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second, // ...
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
}
```

and call `ListenAndServe` on that:

```
log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())
```

Both ways are totally idiomatic, I've seen them used quite frequently.

But seriously, don't take my word for it. Go look at the docs, they have lots of examples :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a hard-and-fast rule to answer your question. I normally use a factory method when one of these conditions holds:

- I need to do some sanity check on the value of the properties prior to the instance being used;
- I want to use unexpected properties, in which case the only way to address them is from within the same package.